# Replace multiple items between tags in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Trying to write a function that will replace #something# and #anything# in any string with items in my db that match the name "something" and "anything".

This should work for no matter how many different #some-name# there are in my string. Below is what I have so far and it's working, although only the last (#anything#) is being replaced with the correct code when I load in my browser.

Please keep in mind that I'm learning, so I may be completely off on how to go about this. If there is a better way, I'm all ears.

HTML (String)

```
<p>This is "#something#" I wanted to replace with code from my database. Really, I could have "#anything#" between my pound sign tags and it should be replaced with text from my database</p>
```

OUTPUT I'm Getting

```
This is "#something#" I want to replace with code from my database. Really, I could have "Any Name" between my pound sign tags and it should be replaced with text from my database
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
This is "The Code" I want to replace with code from my database. Really, I could have "Any Name" between my pound sign tags and it should be replaced with text from my database
```

FUNCTION in CMS class a.php

```
public function get_snippets($string) {
 $regex = "/#(.*?)#/";
 preg_match_all($regex, $string, $names);
 $names = $names[1];
  foreach ($names as $name){
   $find_record = Snippet::find_snippet_code($name);
   $db_name = $find_record->name;
    if($name == $db_name) {
     $snippet_name = "/#".$name."#/";
     $code = $find_record->code;
    }
  }
echo preg_replace($snippet_name, $code, $string);
}
```

FUNCTION in Snippet class b.php

```
public static function find_snippet_code($name) { 
global $database;  
$result_array = static::find_by_sql("SELECT * from ".static::$table_name." WHERE name = '{$name}'"); 
return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `preg_replace` occurs outside of the `foreach()` loop, so it only happens once.
Here is a working example based on your code which returns `$string`.

Note that I also use `PREG_SET_ORDER` which gives me each match as its own array:

```
function get_snippets($string) {
    $regex = '/#([^#]+)#/';
    $num_matches = preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if ($num_matches > 0) {
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            // Each match is an array consisting of the token we matched and the 'name' without the special characters
            list($token, $name) = $match;

            // See if there is a matching record for 'name'
            $find_record = Snippet::find_snippet_code($name);

            // This step might be redundant, but compare name with the record name
            if ($find_record->name == $name) {
                // Replace all instances of #token# with the code from the matched record
                $string = preg_replace('/'.$token.'/', $find_record->code, $string);
            }

        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Now I just need to understand this. Question, you said it was because my preg_replace was out of my foreach() loop. When I tested it in the foreach() loop, it did even crazier things. Was that the only thing wrong, there had to be something else, no?

Comment: In your version you were using `echo()` every time you did the replacement. In the version I provided we work directly on `$string` which is a copy of what was passed to the function. That is the difference that would have caused the strange output within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
public function get_snippets($string) 
{
    $regex = "/#(.*?)#/";
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
        $find_record = Snippet::find_snippet_code($match[1]);
        return $find_record === false ? '' : $find_record->code;
    }, $string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this code didn't work for me though.